# How to change an attribute value in one method and fetch it in another method in backbone.js Model?

Tags: model-view-controller, backbone.js

This is my model:

```
var AppModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
        xmlDeclarationAndDoctype : ''
    },

    renderFoobar : function () {
        this.set({'xmlDeclarationAndDoctype' : 'foobar'});
        this.fetchFoobar();
    }, 
    fetchFoobar : function () {
        console.log(this.get('xmlDeclarationAndDoctype'));
    }, 
    fetchAgain : function () {       
       console.log(this.get('xmlDeclarationAndDoctype'));
    }
});
```

My View:

```
window.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function () {
        model = new AppModel({});
    }, 

    render : function () {
        model.renderFoobar();
    }
});
```

When I call the following code in my HTML page, I get 'foobar' once the page is rendered.

```
$(window).load(function () {
   var appView = new AppView;
});
```

In that page, after clicking a button, I'm calling a function which has the following code but this time I get an empty string instead of 'foobar'.

```
model = new AppModel({});
model.fetchAgain();
```

Whats wrong in above code?

**UPDATES:**

[mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short) has given the valid answer, Thanks a ton!. I just would like to add the excerpt out of the correct answer given below.

The `new AppModel({})` in AppView#initialize is not the same as the `new AppModel({})` somewhere else.

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/sjagf/2/

Comment: @muistooshort: I've updated the question. Please take a look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `new AppModel({})` that you create in `AppView#initialize` is not the same as the `new AppModel({})` that you create in your button's handler. You're looking at the `xmlDeclarationAndDoctype` property of two different models and getting two different results.

Calling `new AppModel(o)`, for some set of options `o`, twice doesn't give you the same object. Backbone doesn't keep track of all the objects that it has created, that's your job or your collection's job. If you look at the `cid` of your models you'll see:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/sjagf/

You probably want a [collection](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection) to help you keep track of your models.

You have more problems. Your view is using a global variable, `model`:

```
window.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function () {
        model = new AppModel({}); // This is a global
    },
```

and that's probably getting overwritten in your button handler. You should attach `model` to `this`:

```
window.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function () {
        this.model = new AppModel({});
    }, 

    render : function () {
        this.model.renderFoobar();
    }
});
```

Or perhaps like this:

```
window.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render : function () {
        this.model.renderFoobar();
    }
});

// And elsewhere...
var v = AppView.new({ model: new AppModel({}) });
```

Comment: Thanks for taking an effort to write that long answer.

Comment: @codef0rmer, remember to upvote and/or accept good answers ;)

Comment: @Acorn: Off-course man! But I'd updated mu's answer a little bit but he has not accepted it yet.